# How to add integrated windows authentication to self hosted Asp.net web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication, self-host-webapi

Is it possible to support integrated windows authentication (Kerberos) in a self hosted web api or is IIS an absolute requirement if integrated window authentication is required ?

Googling around I did not find a clear answer to this question or any sample code that demonstrates how this can be achieved.

I am trying to build self hosted web api that client can authenticate with using windows authentication ( without need to enter username password)

Comment: Haven't tried it (since i'm tied to IIS) but according to the doc it should be possible https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @gsharp That's for ASP.NET Core, but I see no indication in this question that it's about ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @mason oh shoot you are right.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Yeah it sees for a .net framework web api there isn’t an easy option available or at least I have not spot it yet. It’s strange as in plain old WCF world windows authentication is supported out of the box (no IIS needed) but when it comes to self hosted web api it’s a gap. I hope to be proven wrong here.